# Can't Create Custom Forms in SharePoint on-prem (SharePoint 2016 onprem)

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-on-prem

As of yesterday I and my team can no longer create custom forms within a SharePoint list using SharePoint Designer. Looks like it is for any new site and some old sites. I know Microsoft removed this for SharePoint online, but does anyone know if they did it for onprem through a CU?

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing this same issue and opened a case with Microsoft Support about this and this is the response that I received from them:

> This is a reproducible issue/known issue, which was introduced in all versions of SharePoint after the September 2020 CU and all CUs after that contains the same.
>
> This issue has already been reported to the product group team and has been fixed for SharePoint 2019 in the March 2021 CU, and for SharePoint 2016/2013, we are expecting a fix to be released with the May 2021 CU (most probable as far last update given by product group).
> The permanent fix will be released via a cumulative update.
> We have a probable workaround, however it might not work in all cases as below:
>
> - For teams site, we have the workaround to enable the wiki page home page feature after which we have tested that new forms get created successfully, however, this might break the existing custom forms on the site if there are any.
> - On Publishing site, the wiki page home page feature is already enabled by default, and we have seen that the new forms do not work even with this workaround for publishing site.
> - On Publishing sites, only and only if there are no custom forms in working state, we can try disabling and re-enabling the wiki page home page feature as a workaround for the new forms to work.
>
> Note: Please do not use the workaround of disabling and re-enabling the feature on any site/subsite where you have previously created custom forms in working state, as this might break the existing/working forms.